# Debugging twisted application using PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, twisted, pycharm

I am fighting a few hours trying to configure PyCharm for debugging my app. I was looking for solution, but twisted seems to not be so popular and there is weak support. Below I put error log that i got.

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.4m -u /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 57276 57277 /usr/bin/twistd -y /Users/artur/projs/private/elanga-web/start_app.tac
Running /usr/bin/twistd
PyDev console: starting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/twistd", line 7, in <module>
    import _preamble
ImportError: No module named '_preamble'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 68, in <module>
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 28, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "/usr/bin/twistd", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exc_clear()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exc_clear'

Process finished with exit code 1
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

I will be grateful for an answer why there is no such module like `_preamble`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OS X, `/usr/bin/twistd` is a version of Twisted installed into the system python.  This is not python 3.4.  The symptom you're seeing is not the missing `_preamble` module (which is in fact *not* supposed to be installed, which is why there is an `except` block around that import catching the exception) but rather that you have pointed python 3.4 at some random python 2 program.

If you want to run python 3.4, you need to create a python 3 environment with Twisted installed.  Keep in mind that not all of Twisted is ported, so only a subset of APIs will be available to you.  One of the things that is not ported to python 3 yet is the `twistd` command line, so there's no way to run `twistd` with python 3 yet.